# Symfony2 Form component - violating MVC and SRP?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, design-patterns, symfony, single-responsibility-principle

The more I use Symfony2 and struggle with it's forms the more I come to the conclusion that they are a massive scary beast that shouldn't even really exist.

I have come upon this article  [here](http://arialdomartini.wordpress.com/2011/04/01/how-to-kill-symfony%E2%80%99s-forms-and-live-well/) and I find that I agree with the author. Even if the article is for Symfony 1.x I think it still holds for the Form component in Symfony2. It really seems like the form component tries to solve problems that belong in the template, controller and model, all in one place. Doesn't this severely violate the MVC and/or SRP (Single responsibility principle)?

This may be a different question but I feel it is kind of related - I have also noticed that a lot of the available bundles for symfony try to solve view issues outside the view, for example:

KnpMenuBundle - you generate menus on server side with an oo-interface (why not in view layer where they belong?)

IvoryCKEditorBundle - converting textarea to ckeditor is done in one jquery line in the view file, so why does this bundle exist? I don't even want to count the number of lines in there.

So it kind of seems like there are these violations everywhere in the core of Symfony or am I just not getting it?

Comment: Those are 3rd party tools. While there are design flaws in Sf2, the SRP violation in the actual core of framework are minimal and applied only when it is the pragmatic solution. What you are looking at is not the core.

Comment: I meant that it seems like somewhere in the core idea of Symfony something exists that drives people to write these crazy bundles. But isn't the Form component a core component of the framework?

Comment: There are such components in Zend Framework, but it's quite awful. I have come to the conclusion that creating any sort of fits-all form builders is quite a futile undertaking.

Comment: would you generate your menus client side ? Please choose your words. Separation of concerns are maintened in KnpMenu, markup generation is delegated to a view layer, while menu hierarchy is delegated to a specific class. Where is the problem ? I'll answer you: to use it to create a dead simple 3 items menu :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem about form processing is that it violates MVC by definition. This is a problem known as "crosscutting" and has been studied by science in the past. The paper [Domain Driven Web Development With WebJinn](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~lorenz/papers/oopsla03b/oopsla03b.pdf), for example, is an interesting read about the topic.

As an example, think about the relation of forms to the different layers of MVC:

**Model:**

- Forms replicate the *informational structure* of your domain model (DM). If you change this structure (e.g. by adding fields to a data structure or by adding parameters to a procedure), you must also adapt the forms for entering that information.
- They need *type information* from your DM to convert input to the types required there.
- They need to know the *constraints* specified in your DM to validate the input.
- They ideally read and write data directly from/to your DM (e.g. by reading/writing fields of a data structure or by invoking a procedure in the DM with the submitted values as parameters).

**Controller:**

- Forms receive submitted data and send it to the DM.
- They alter the program flow depending on whether they validate successfully or not.

**View:**

- Forms render as a complex structure of HTML tags and attributes that depends on all of the above (Should a field be required? Should errors be displayed? How to order the fields? What choices to offer in a drop-down? etc.)

Consequently, it is *impossible* to write a form abstraction mechanism that does not touch all of these layers. The solution, on the contrary, is to structure the form library itself according to MVC, into different layers and sub-components that fulfill the SRP. If you look into the Symfony2 Form component, it does so pretty well. ;)

So why is it such a "massive scary beast"? The first problem is that of abstraction. Think of a simple drop-down for example. If we want to reuse the code for the drop-down, we need to abstract it somehow. Now check the list above, even this simple input touches all three layers of an MVC application. How can you abstract something that is meant to be structured into three different parts?

The second problem is feature diversity. Form libraries never solve all the problems that developers face in their daily lives. So all these layers and abstraction mechanisms need to be extensible so that you can make them behave exactly like you want them to.

While being extensible, the Form component already solves hundreds of tiny problems that you don't even have to think about anymore. How to input dates, how to select one or many of a list of choices using different UIs  (drop-downs, checkboxes, radio buttons, etc.), how to protect forms again security flaws and many more are topics that I could write essays about.

You see that form libraries turn out to be quite complex. The best bet that we have at writing such "massive scary beasts" is to make their API as simple as possible for beginners, as flexible as possible for more advanced users and to write extensive documentation about leveraging its full power. The last point is definitely still lacking ([please help!](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues)), but we're continually working on all of the above.

Reducing a complex to a simple problem, on the other hand, is unfortunately not possible.

What about other form libraries out there that are so much simpler? In my humble opinion, these don't even try to address a majority of the problems that the Symfony2 Form component already solves for you. :)

**Update January 24, 2014:** For anybody that wants to know more (much more), here's [a paper that I published on the subject](https://webmozart.io/files/bsc-thesis.pdf).

Comment: Would you mind elaborating what you consider to be a *domain model*? If anything, the Symfony forms component stimulates anemic models...

Comment: Let me clarify what I'm asking for. You say for example: **Forms replicate the structure of your domain model (DM).**

I could not disagree with you more strongly. They should allow you to modify the domain model by executing methods that represent behavior. Putting your domain model into forms is one of the worst presuppositions the Form component is build on.

Comment: I was referring to the informational structure. If your domain model models "employees" and you have forms for modifying the data of these employees, you will very likely have to adapt the forms if your domain model's informational structure changes (e.g. you remove the birth date but add a social insurance number instead).

Comment: What I'm saying is that Symfony is wrong when it is asking me to inject my domain model into a form. When a user submits a form it is basically telling the application: perform operation n with data x, y and z. For that to happen I don't have to inject my domain model in a form. That frees my model from having to expose it's state which relieves a lot. The symfony form component however is asking me to do that stuff, with getters and setters, leaving most users with an anemic model. It seems like the real deal but it's just a data model, nothing more nothing less, without any value.

Comment: You are right that submitting a form is the equivalent of performing operation n with data x, y and z. But n is also part of your DM. If you change its signature (e.g. remove z), you are also changing the informational structure of the DM. Now, passing your data objects to the form layer is an *option* in Symfony to speed up coding in certain circumstances - that is, when n corresponds to writing x, y and z into that object - but it is in no way mandatory.

Comment: I have adapted the "Model" part of my answer to clarify this.

Comment: "What I'm saying is that Symfony is wrong when it is asking me to inject my domain model into a form" you dont have to , forms can have their own models , then you can pass the form model into the service that will use this model and domain models.take a registration form you can have an register model for RegisterType and a user model not used in the controller. that's what i do. symfony doesnt force anything. my controllers dont know anything about domain models , my services do.

Comment: Very nice rundown. I now have a better understanding of the complex problems the form component tries to solve.